# JavaFX WebView - Get "Copy Link to Clipboard"-function

Tags: url, javafx, webview, contextmenu

I want to get the URL of a link of a website in WebView. By default you can use the default ContextMenu and right click on the link and select "Copy Link to Clipboard". But I have a custom ContextMenu, so I can't use that. Is there a way to access that method or another way of getting the URL of the link that is right-clicked?
So far I have an ActionListener that refers to the MenuItem and not the link.

```java
   public void createContextMenu() {
      ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();

      MenuItem menuItem_download = new MenuItem("Download");
      contextMenu.getItems().add(menuItem_download);

      menuItem_download.setOnAction(e -> fileDownloadContextMenu(e));

      webView.setOnMousePressed(e -> {
         if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
            contextMenu.show(webView, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
         } else{
            contextMenu.hide();
         }
      });
   }
```

```java
   public void fileDownloadContextMenu(Event e) {

      System.out.println(e.getSource());
      
      // Code for downloading
   }
```

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
I tried this for the concatenated String:

```java
   private final String getHrefJs = "var elt = document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f);\n" +
            "var href = \"\";\n" +
            "if (elt.tagName.toLowerCase() == \"a\"){\n" +
            "href = elt.getAttribute(\"href\");}\n" +
            "href\n";
```

**EDIT 2:**
For debugging I did this:

```java
private void showMenuIfNeeded(double x, double y) throws URISyntaxException {

      String js = String.format(getHrefJs, x, y);
      Object href = engine.executeScript(js);
      System.out.println(js);

      if (href == null) {
         System.out.println("null");
      } else {
         System.out.println("not null:");
         System.out.println(href.getClass());
         System.out.println(href.toString().isEmpty());
      }


      if (href != null && href.toString().length() > 0) {
         System.out.println("checkup");
         link = new URI(engine.getLocation()).resolve(href.toString()).toString();
         contextMenu.show(webView, Side.TOP, x, y);
      }
   }
```

The console output looks like this:

```
var elt = document.elementFromPoint(53,000000, 150,000000);
var href = "";
if (elt.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a"){
href = elt.getAttribute("href");}
href

not null:
class java.lang.String
true
```

So somehow "href" is not null but empty and therefore the following if-statement is not executed. That is why the ContextMenu ist not showing. But I don't know why "href" is empty.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're trying to do. If you have your own context menu set on the web view, then won't that context menu show any time you right-click on the web view (i.e. whether or not you're clicking on a link)? Do you want a different context menu (or at least different set of menu items) to show depending on whether or not you click on a link?

Comment: Take the following site: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/. This would be displayed in the WebView. As soon as a link is right clicked, the ContextMenu is displayed and I click on the MenuItem "Download". There the URL of the link should be displayed (maybe first in the console), where it was right clicked. For the correct download I need this URL.

Comment: And yes, still the ContextMenu is always shown as soon as you right-click somewhere. I would also like to solve that at some point. But I didn't want to ask too many questions at once and rather solve my main problem.

Comment: If you want the menu only to be shown when you right-click a link, it might be easier to solve both problems at once. I'm not a Javascript expert, but I think you can retrieve the topmost HTML element at given coordinates (which you can get from the mouse event) using Javascript, and then if it's an anchor tag retrieve the `href` attribute, otherwise just return an empty string. Have your event handler execute that Javascript, and the result is a non-empty string show the context menu with the option to copy the returned link.

Answer (score 2):

You can use some Javascript to retrieve the link if the right-click is over an `A` tag. Then just use some standard JavaFX to copy it to the clipboard.

The Javascript strategy is just to lookup the HTML element at the mouse coordinates, check its tagname and then retrieve the `href` attribute from it if it is an anchor.

There may be easier ways to achieve this, but this seems to work.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.input.Clipboard;
import javafx.scene.input.ClipboardContent;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class HelloApplication extends Application {

    private String link;
    private WebView webView;
    private WebEngine engine;
    private ContextMenu contextMenu;

    private final String getHrefJs = """
                var elt = document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f);
                var href = "";
                if (elt.tagName.toLowerCase() == "a") {
                    href = elt.getAttribute("href");
                }
                href
        """;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        webView = new WebView();
        webView.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
        engine = webView.getEngine();
        engine.load("https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/");

        MenuItem copyLink = new MenuItem("Copy link address");
        Label linkLabel = new Label();
        copyLink.setOnAction(e -> {
            linkLabel.setText(link);
            Clipboard clipboard = Clipboard.getSystemClipboard();
            ClipboardContent content = new ClipboardContent();
            content.putString(link);
            clipboard.setContent(content);
        });

        contextMenu = new ContextMenu(copyLink);

        webView.setOnContextMenuRequested(e -> {
            try {
                showMenuIfNeeded(e.getX(), e.getY());
            } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
                throw new RuntimeException(ex);
            }
        });

        BorderPane root = new BorderPane(webView);
        root.setTop(linkLabel);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    private void showMenuIfNeeded(double x, double y) throws URISyntaxException {

        String js = String.format(getHrefJs, x, y);
        Object href = engine.executeScript(js);

        if (href != null && href.toString().length() > 0) {
            link = new URI(engine.getLocation()).resolve(href.toString()).toString();
            contextMenu.show(webView, Side.TOP, x, y);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have Java 15 and therefore I can't use this feature with the text block with "getHrefJs". I tried to rewrite it in "the old way", but it did not work. Is there something I have to consider when rewriting the text block in the old way with multi line String?

Comment: @Katapa Why don't you just update to Java 15 (or a more recent version)? But there is nothing special; you can just use a concatenated string here. Obviously you will have to escape the embedded quotation marks.

Comment: Company policy is preventing that, unfortunately. My concatenated String looks like this:
   private final String getHrefJs = "var elt = document.elementFromPoint(%f, %f);\n" +
            "var href = \"\";\n" +
            "if (elt.tagName.toLowerCase() == \"a\"){\n" +
            "href = elt.getAttribute(\"href\");}\n" +
            "href\n";
But rightclick to a link does not open the ContextMenu. When I delete the last line ("href\n";) I get a ContextMenu and can copy the address, but at the end of the URL it says "undefined" (of course because href is missing)

Comment: I edited the original question, because the concatenated string is easier to see this way.

Comment: @Katapa It works just fine for me with the string you posted in the question.

Comment: This is so strange. The full String does not open a ContextMenu. When I delete the last line I get the ContextMenu, but get undefined, because the "href" is missing.

Comment: I'd debug by having the javascript evaluate to the element, or its tag name, and just printing out what it gives you to the console.

Comment: I edited the post for the debugging (don't know if users get notified when I edit the post, so therefore I answer here).