# Clicking on menu item "open in new tab" on webview does not open webpage sometimes, other time it does open

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-webengine

I have a piece of code in JavaFX which creates a small web browser. The web page is shown in a web view. I have managed to get custom context menu popped up by right clicking on the links on the webpage. The context menu has a menu item labeled "open in new tab". However, I have a strange problem. If I click on the "open in new tab", sometimes related webpage opens in new tab, but other times it fails to do so. Please note that if I implement the functionality without any context menu and using right click alone directly on the link, the link opens every time in new tab. How do we describe the situation? Is it a threading issue? I have tested the code on Windows 7 64-bit and Windows 8.1 64-bit. I am using BlueJ on Java 17 and JavaFX 20.

Here is what I have tried.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEvent;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;

public class QuickTab extends Application
{
    TabPane tpane;
    TextField urlField;
    WebView webView;
    String url;
    public void start(Stage stage)
    {
        tpane = new TabPane();
        Tab urlTab = new Tab();
        HBox box = new HBox();
        urlField = new TextField();
        urlField.setPromptText("Enter URL");
        Button goBtn = new Button("Go");
        goBtn.setOnAction(e -> load_page());
        box.getChildren().addAll(urlField, goBtn);
        urlTab.setGraphic(box);
        tpane.getTabs().add(urlTab);
        
        stage.setScene(new Scene(tpane, 400, 300));
        stage.show();
    }
    private void load_page()
    {
        webView = new WebView();
        WebEngine engine = webView.getEngine();
        webView.setContextMenuEnabled(false);//***
        Tab tab = new Tab("home tab");
        tab.setContent(webView);
        tpane.getTabs().add(tab);      
        
        engine.setOnStatusChanged((WebEvent<String> event) -> {
            url = event.getData();
            
        });
        engine.load(urlField.getText());       
        webView.setOnMouseClicked(new TabOpener());
    }
    private class TabOpener implements EventHandler<MouseEvent>
    {
                 
        public void handle(MouseEvent e)
        {
            if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY)
            {
                ContextMenu cmenu = new ContextMenu();
                MenuItem item = new MenuItem("open in new tab"); 
                cmenu.getItems().addAll(item);
                cmenu.show(webView, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());                    
                item.setOnAction(event -> {
                    Platform.runLater(() -> load_newPage());
                });
            }
            e.consume();
        }
        private void load_newPage()
        {
            WebView newView = new WebView();
            WebEngine newEngine = newView.getEngine();
            Tab newTab = new Tab(url);
            tpane.getTabs().add(newTab);
            newTab.setContent(newView);
            newEngine.load(url);
            
        }
    }    
}
```

Comment: You seem to be relying on the Javascript engine reporting the url of a link when the user hovers on it via a status change on the web engine. I can't see that this behavior is documented anywhere (though I may be wrong). Have you tried debugging your status listener to see if it is doing what you expect and passing the expected url? In some quick tests this seems to work for me.

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but why are you using `Platform.runLater(....)`? You are already on the FX Application Thread here. And setting the event handler on the menu item *after* showing the context menu seems counter-intuitive, at best.

Comment: Yes I have verified that the code retrieves the url. the code works fine if I modify the same code to open the link in another tab by directly right clicking the link. But problem arises when I add action to menu item of context menu. And without Platform.runLater() the code does not run at all. In this case the code opens web page in new tab sometimes and some times does not. without the Platform.runLater() it does nothing. Correct ,me if I am wrong and help me with where I am missing.

Comment: You can check by using System.out.println(url);

Comment: Yes status listener is working well.

Comment: Did you try setting the `onAction` handler before showing the context menu. It makes no sense to me to do it in the order you have done it. I can't replicate the issue; it works fine for me (though I haven't tested much). I removed the redundant `Platform.runLater(...)` call and it still works. Did you try logging the value of `url` in `loadNewPage()`?

Comment: Very strange. In my system the code is giving inconsistent result. I have 2 systems, windows 7 and windows 8.1. Do I have my compiler BluJ 5.2.0 to blame?

Comment: I did what you suggested. No difference. And you right. "url" in loadNewPage() is not logging. It is not null, but simply does not show up in system.out.println() in loadNewPage().

Comment: I checked that setting the order of item.setOnAction() had no effect. Neither Platform.runLater() method had any bearing. I am thinking more thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear how your program is going awry, but I see distinct code paths to add a new `Tab`: one gets a context listener, one doesn't.

One approach is to minimize unrelated class level attributes, while *aggregating* relevant fields with the corresponding `Tab`. In the variation below,

- All `Tab` instances have access to the containing `TabPane` and a shared `ContextMenu`; the remaining attributes are local to each `WebTab`.
- The initial `Tab` opens on the `HOME` page.
- Each `Tab` gets an editable URL; edit and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> to load the page; press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to change tabs.
- The context menu simply opens the current page in a new `Tab`, allowing continued browsing in the current `Tab`.
- Also consider isolating individual links, illustrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75795295/230513), or parsing the document, shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73528614/230513).

[image: Tab browser]

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.web.WebView;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent;
import javafx.scene.web.WebEngine;

//https://stackoverflow.com/q/77506981/230513
public class QuickTab extends Application {

    private static final String HOME = "https://example.edu";
    private final TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    private final MenuItem item = new MenuItem("Open this page in a new tab.");
    private final ContextMenu menu = new ContextMenu(item);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        tabPane.getTabs().add(new WebTab(HOME).tab());
        stage.setScene(new Scene(tabPane));
        stage.show();
    }

    private class WebTab {

        private final Tab tab = new Tab();
        private final TextField urlField = new TextField();
        private final WebView view = new WebView();
        private final WebEngine engine = view.getEngine();
        private String url;

        private WebTab(String s) {
            url = s;
            view.setContextMenuEnabled(false);
            tab.setGraphic(urlField);
            tab.setContent(view);
            urlField.focusedProperty().addListener((obs, ov, isFocused) -> {
                if (isFocused) {
                    tabPane.getSelectionModel().select(tab);
                }
            });
            urlField.setOnKeyPressed((KeyEvent e) -> {
                KeyCode code = e.getCode();
                if (KeyCode.ENTER == code) {
                    engine.load(urlField.getText());
                }
            });
            engine.locationProperty().addListener((obs, ov, nv) -> {
                url = nv;
                urlField.setText(nv);
            });
            view.setOnMouseClicked((e) -> {
                if (e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY) {
                    menu.show(view, e.getScreenX(), e.getScreenY());
                    item.setOnAction(event -> {
                        tabPane.getTabs().add(new WebTab(url).tab());
                    });
                }
                e.consume();
            });
            engine.load(url);
            urlField.setText(url);
        }

        public Tab tab() {
            return tab;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch();
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate that you gave me a response. Your code is very informative. However opening the same web page in new tab was not my issue. What I wanted is to open the links given in the web page in another tab, just as you do while using other browsers.  I would highly appreciate if you could help me in this direction. But I thank you very much for your response and time given to answer me.

Comment: Excellent; it sounds like the link is opening reliably, now. You can [edit] your question to clarify this requirement; include a [mre] showing any problem you encounter with your chosen approach; honestly, it seems like a new question. In any case, the code in this answer might be a useful foundation.

Comment: Just give me a little time and I will come up with my edited code. However if you look at my code you will find that my intention was to open clicked link in new tab. Only issue was that the web page did not  consistently appear in  "new tab" when I clicked the menu item "open in new tab". But I have figured out the problem and made changes in my code. Once again I am grateful to the insights which you have provided. I have also gone through the links you mentioned and those links were very relevant. I would show up very soon. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For reference, you might also look at the approach outlined [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47747290/230513) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17555937/230513).